# Swift Realm - get types of all database objects

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I have a list of various objects in my Realm Database all of which are created as default `ClassName: Object` classes. Is there any way to get types (classes names) of those objects, that can be saved as variables, or create an enum of these types?

Comment: For clarity; are you saying you're created Realm objects in your database but you don't know what class they are? In general, the Realm objects cannot be instantiated without an object model existing in code. Can you clarify what's being asked?

Comment: I have created Realm objects and I know exactly what classes they are but I want to have these classes types in one place, for example an array or an enum so that I can use them to make switch or if statements or iterate over them quickly

Comment: Well, that can be made to work but probably not like you think. Let me post an answer and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Realm `Results` objects are homogenous - they only contain one object type. That translates to meaning you will never have a situation where Results would contain `Person` and `Dog` classes at the same time.

That being said we have the option of using the Realm [AnyRealmValue](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/supported-types/#anyrealmvalue)

Let me set this up: Suppose you have a PersonClass and a DogClass

```
let dog = DogClass()
let person = PersonClass()
```

and a class with a List that can contain AnyRealmValue

```
class MyClass: Object {
   @Persisted var myList = List<AnyRealmValue>()
}
```

when then need to cast those objects to AnyRealmValue to make this work

```
let obj0: AnyRealmValue = .object(dog)
let obj1: AnyRealmValue = .object(person)
```

and we add those to the List

```
let m = MyClass()
m.myList.append(obj0)
m.myList.append(obj1)
```

You mentioned `switch` but here's a simple if...then clause to handle them differently - depending on the class

```
if let person = item.object(PersonClass.self) {
   print("is a person")
} else if let dog = item.object(DogClass.self) {
   print("is a dog")
}
```